# TypeError: integer argument expected got float' Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-2to3

I get a error of a integer expected a float so I change it and then get the reverse saying a float can not be a integer. I had similar issues before and just changed it to have the int.

I am learning via tutorials in python27 but have for the most part got them to work in python34 via troubleshooting. This one I got stuck on.

**TypeError: integer argument expected go float'**

```
for tile in return_tiles:
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, [34, 95, 200],
    [tile.x + half - 2, tile.y + half - 2], 5 )
```

So I then made the change below it would usually work like the one under this one but in this case get a error

**TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as a integer**

```
   for tile in return_tiles:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (34, 95, 200), (int(tile.x + half -2),int(half - 2, tile.y + half - 2)), int(5))
```

example of how I fixed another one below that was a integer but in the case above it did not work

```
 pygame.draw.circle(screen, (34, 95, 200), (int(tile.x + half -2),int(half - 2, tile.y + half - 2)), int(5))
```

I been teaching myself by learning tutorials online but most are for earlier version 2.7 etc of python. But that has not been a problem for the most part. I been just using the the error msg and for the most part I can figure it out if not sometimes I run 2to3.py or search to find the answer.

Comment: `int(half - 2, tile.y + half - 2))` 
seems like the brackets are not in the right place

Change it to: `circle(screen, (1, 2, 3), (int(tile.x+half-2), int(tile.y+half-2)), 5)`

Comment: thx, pygame.draw.circle(screen, (34, 95, 200), (int(tile.x+half-2), int(tile.y+half-2)), 5)

Comment: @johntaylor now did it work

Comment: it did fix that line but the overall issue was half variable  float needed to be set to a int like bakkal pointed out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect your culprit is the `half` variable, since it involves a **division**, in Python 2 it'll give you an `int`, however in Python 3 a division will give a `float` unless you use the int division operator `//`

If you're using Python 2 tutorials, they didn't have to deal with that

**Python 3**

```
>>> 5 // 3
1
>>> 5 / 3
1.6666666666666667
```

So I would go look for where `half` is calculated, and either coerce to `int` with `half = int(...)` or use `//`

In pygame it's not very useful to use `float` for pixel dimensions, so just keep everything in `int`, especially when you do divisions like for `half`, the rest of arithmetics like `tile.x + half` will yield an `int` if both operands are `int`s, so there is no need to coerce

Comment: A solution for this problem when dealing with python 2/3 compatilibity issues is to add the following line to the top of your file(s):

`from __future__ import division`

This will make division in python 2 behave like it does in python 3

Comment: I changed it from I changed it to half = Tile.width / 2 into half = int(Tile.width / 2) I got a bunch of other issues before this will run but I now understand how to fix this one going forward. thx again.